# Using google.maps.importLibrary API, Want To Add A Circle Around PIN

Tags: javascript, google-maps, drawing, import-libraries

I have seen API calls that do not use the Import Library method.

Like:

```
cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(sunCircle);
cityCircle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
```

But I am using the Import Library.

Everything else works in my code but the circle.

I get Error: The library circle is unknown.

I follow the link it recommends. I do not know whether to use drawing or geometery.

Using the search on api documentation for circle radius never shows anything involving importing library.

I appreciate any guidance.

My Code that creates the PIN. This is inside an object ModGPS (attempting some resemblance To OOP.)

```
    PinIt : async function ( sComp, sName, nLat, nLon, nRadius, sFunc = 'PinIt' )
    {
        if ( ModGPS.debug )    console.log( ModGPS.Object + '    ' + sFunc + '()' ) ;
        
        const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary( "maps" ) ;
        const { Marker } = await google.maps.importLibrary( "marker" ) ;
        const { Circle } = await google.maps.importLibrary( "circle" ) ;
        
        let oPosition = { lat : nLat, lng : nLon, } ;
        
        let oCoord =
        {
            zoom   : 18,
            center : oPosition ,
            mapId  : 'Company_Properties',
        } ;
        
        let NewMap = new Map( ModGPS.dom.Map, oCoord ) ;
        
        let sDisplay = ".\n \n      " + sComp + "   " + sName + "      \n \n." ;
        
        const marker = new Marker( { map : NewMap, position : oPosition, title : sDisplay, } ) ;
        
        const circle = new Circle(
            {
                strokeColor   : "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity : 0.8,
                strokeWeight  : 2,
                fillColor     : "#FF0000",
                fillOpacity   : 0.35,
                NewMap,
                center        : oPosition,
                radius        : nRadius,
            }
        ) ;
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The `Circle` class is still within the `"maps"` library

There's no such thing as `"circle"` library in the API. As I can see in your code, you are trying to import the `Circle` class in this way:

```
const { Circle } = await google.maps.importLibrary("circle")
```

Please note that there's nothing on the official documentation which says that this is how you import the `Circle` class.

If you go to the [Circle Class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#Circle) section in the Reference Documentation, you can access the class by calling,

```
const {Circle} = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps")
```

This means that the `Circle` class is still included within the `"maps"` core library. And that the `"circle"` library you used as an argument to `.importLibrary` is non-existent as described by the error you encountered:

`Error: The library circle is unknown`

Here's a sample code snippet for you to see it working fine with the mentioned solution above:

```js
// Initialize and add the map
let map;

async function initMap() {
  // The location of Uluru
  const position = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.031 };
  // Request needed libraries.
  //@ts-ignore
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
  // This is how you correctly import the Circle class
    const { Circle } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");

  // The map, centered at Uluru
  map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: position,
    mapId: "DEMO_MAP_ID",
  });

  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
  const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map: map,
    position: position,
    title: "Uluru",
  });
    
  // instantiating the circle here:
    const circle = new Circle({
        center: position,
        radius: 1000000,
        map: map,
    })
}



initMap();
```

```css
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */
/* 
  * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
  * that contains the map. 
  */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
  @license
  Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
  SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Polygon</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
<script>
  (g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})({
    key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk",
    v: "weekly",
    // Use the 'v' parameter to indicate the version to use (weekly, beta, alpha, etc.).
    // Add other bootstrap parameters as needed, using camel case.
  });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Yrll.  This Helped.

After adding the colors, the final product is spot on!

The final code I scripted with the help you provided:

```
    PinIt : async function ( sComp, sName, nLat, nLon, nBubble, sFunc = 'PinIt' )
    {
        if ( ModGPS.debug )    console.log( ModGPS.Object + '    ' + sFunc + '() nBubble: ' + nBubble ) ;
        
        const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary( "maps" ) ;
        const { Marker } = await google.maps.importLibrary( "marker" ) ;
        const { Circle } = await google.maps.importLibrary( "maps" ) ;
        
        let oPosition = { lat : nLat, lng : nLon, } ;
        
        let oCoord =
        {
            zoom   : 17,
            center : oPosition ,
            mapId  : 'Company_Properties',
        } ;
        
        let NewMap = new Map( ModGPS.dom.Map, oCoord ) ;
        
        let sDisplay = ".\n \n      " + sComp + "   " + sName + "      \n \n." ;
        
        const marker = new Marker(
            {
                map      : NewMap,
                position : oPosition,
                title    : sDisplay,
            }
        ) ;
        
        nRadius = nBubble / 2 ;
        
        const circle = new Circle(
            {
                center        : oPosition,
                map           : NewMap,
                radius        : nRadius,
                fillColor     : "#FF0000",
                fillOpacity   : 0.35,
                strokeColor   : "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity : 0.8,
                strokeWeight  : 2,
            }
        ) ;
    },
```